# How to create custom itemize-unfolding-animations in beamer

Tags: beamer, animate

I'm still a newbie in beamer so sorry if it's a simple question: I want to animate an "unfolding of itemize" in a custom way. So instead of the standard:

```
\begin{itemize} 
    \item<1-> item-1
    \item<2-> item-2
    \item<3-> item-3
\end{itemize}
```

I want the `item-i` that are not "in focus" to be grayed out. The following code does exactly what I want:

```
\def\colorize<#1>{%
 \temporal<#1>{\color{black!50}}{\color{black}}{\color{black!50}}}

\begin{itemize} 
    \colorize<1>\item item-1
    \colorize<2>\item item-2
    \colorize<3>\item item-3
\end{itemize}
```

However, it's a lot of code to write `colorize<i>` every time.

My question: is there a way to define a macro (lets call it `grayoutunhighlighted`) so that I could do something like: `\begin{itemize}[<-+| grayoutunhighlighted@+>]`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a simple solution:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+-+>]
    \item item-1
    \item item-2
    \item item-3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You can use the optional argument of the `itemize` environment which is defined by `beamer` itself.

Comment: Great - that solves this specific case! But do you know the answer to the more general question - how to define such a itemize-uncovering-template?

Comment: @Guy: Sorry I don't understand what you want?

Comment: Sorry: is there a way to define a macro (lets call it `grayoutunhighlighted`) so that I could do something like: `\begin{itemize}[<-+| grayoutunhighlighted@+>]`? (For example, if I want to control the colors of the un-highlighted items)